# JavaScript: How do you do unicode form validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, unicode, utf-8

This is not working on Edge but fine on Chrome.

```js
...
patterns.fname = /^[\p{Lu}]{1}[\p{L}]{1,15}$/gu
patterns.lname = /^[\p{Lu}]{1}[\-_0-9 \p{L}]{1,15}$/gu
...
myinput.match(patterns.fname);
myinput.match(patterns.lname);
```

Answer (score 0):

[It's not implemented.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_property_escapes)

Use [downcompiled compatibility](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-property-regex) or try http://xregexp.com/.